# How to show html formatted content (without image) in a winform?

Tags: c#, .net, html, vb.net, winforms

I want to show html formatted string in my winform application. What control should I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control to display html content in WinForms applications.

You can specify just html content:

```
Dim html As string  = "<span>my html content</span>"
webBrowser.DocumentText = html
```

or specify path to the html content:

```
webBrowserNotes.Url = "my-html-content.html"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want "simple" HTML formatting (e.g. underline, bold, text color, etc) you could use this custom control from Oscar Londono on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/htmlrichtextbox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use `WebBrowser` Control. Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser control. You can find it under common controls.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `WebBrowser` Control would be a good option. But if you want to use HTML5 you would be better of looking at .NET web browser libraries such as [GeckoFX](http://www.webprogrammingblog.com/c-sharp-firefox-web-browser-geckofx/)