# c# is it possible to show a live webpage in a windows form application?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if its possible to show a webpage inside of a windows form application.
I'm trying to create a livechat client,but it seems to hard for a c# beginner,since I have to code the server side also. So I was wondering if it's possible to show a php page containing the chat client into a window of my application?

Thanks in advance for any replay!

Comment: Maybe you should concentrate on the server side part first and use a normal browser as frontend.

Comment: A little searching goes a long way. Found this at the top of my first search for your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514328/how-to-show-html-formatted-content-without-image-in-a-winform

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. Place it to your form and call `Navigate` method:

```
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Can I somehow change the background color of the web browser..? Like making the web page background green for example?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Web browser doesn't support css grid (when it loads pages that are using css grid everything on page scews up), is there any alternative to that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use a WebBrowser control. It does exactly what you're describing: show a web page from within a winforms application. It is essentially Internet Explorer from within a control.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a WebBrowser control available in windows forms.  You can navigate this page to any webpage you would like.

Answer (score 3):

you can try CefSharp.WinForms.

it is more easier than webbrowser control.

---

After you add all it's reference dll

just use this simple line of code:

```
uri = "https://www.google.com/";
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(uri);
panel.Controls.Add(browser);
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Webview2 instead of the old web browser control, as it supports many modern html/css features.

To use it, in project package manager (assuming you're using MS Visual Studio) search for WebView2 and install the Microsoft's one; then a "WebView2" control will appear in form designer toolbox. Drag it onto the form to add it.

For more information, read the official documentation on Microsoft's site:
"Get started with WebView2 - Microsoft Edge Development | Microsoft Docs" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/get-started

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).