# Run Chrome inside a VS Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

**NOTE: I DO NOT WANT TO USE webBrowser.navigate() as it is too old school. I doesn't support Haml and other languages which Chrome can support** 

I have been facing this problem for quite a while now. I have been creating a VS Form with C# where a particular website is run inside chrome inside the form. I want to run google.com inside the form but the Web Browser in VS is pretty old and doesn't support scss and stuff (what I use). So I was thinking, of running Chrome inside the form and displaying a website. I referred to multiple sources and it worked for each of them, but none of them worked.
The following is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;




namespace Display_App
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }




        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
                try
                {

                    Process p = Process.Start("chrome.exe","https://google.com");
                    p.WaitForInputIdle();
                    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not want to add something like "button1_click". I want the user to have chrome and the website open the moment it opens. Since it was not working, I used try and catch. But it showed the message box and opened Chrome and the website successfully but not inside the form but inside Chrome.
Anyone got ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Could someone please help me quickly....

Comment: As suggested in the duplicate, [WebView2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537641/1690217) is the standard workaround for this, I haven't found a scenario that cannot be covered by that, you even get full programatic access to the dev tools if you need to run any advanced diagnostics.

Comment: If  WebView2 does not suite your need maybe you will like https://cefsharp.github.io/ (Chromium Embedded Framework)