# Is it possible to invoke an HTML language service within a string in c# and visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a component that returns HTML, something like this:

```
interface IComponent
{
    string Render();
}

public class MyComponent : IComponent
{
    public string Render()
    {
        return $"<div class="..."></div>";
    }
}
```

Because Render returns a plain C# string, the compiler knows nothing of the structure of HTML, and so doesn't provide all the help you'd get if that snippet were in an HTML file, like tag completion, knowledge about the possible attributes, the different styles in a style attribute, etc.

Is there any way to hook up the HTML language service in Visual Studio to a C# string, such that you could get Intellisense on a string in this way, kind of like how JSX works in React:

```
function HelloWorld() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>World</p>
    </>
  );
```

Or, failing that, to make an HTML file that is aware of a C# model, kind of like a Razor page, but without the dependency on Razor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# is it possible to show a live webpage in a windows form application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618127/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-show-a-live-webpage-in-a-windows-form-application)

Comment: What dependencies can you accept? Pure C#?

Comment: @nbk No. I'm not trying to view HTML but to generate it.

Comment: @shingo: I'd prefer pure C#, but I could live with some external components. The reason I want to avoid Razor is that it comes with HUGE dependencies on ASP.NET, which creates a huge runtime and lots of DLL Hell, in my experience so far.

Comment: html is only text, but your question is about showing it.