# Display HTML on a winform

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I'm developing a win-form application that needs sometime to show a "pop-up" form that displays a portion of a web page on internet (HTML).
I'm getting the HTML of the page using a classic web request:

```
 var serviceRequest = new WebClient();
 var response = serviceRequest.DownloadString(new Uri("www.something.com"));
```

I have already tried to use the **web browser** control which works really well but as you know there are several issue using  it as it is based on a COM object.(I cannot dynamically create another form that contains the web browser control without create a thread STA etc)

All I need is "container" where I can inject the HTML I want to display.

Any suggestions?

thanks a lot

Comment: Note: Strictly speaking, this question is about specifically _avoiding_ the use of the WinForms [`WebBrowser` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser). However, the question's generic title has prompted answers recommending precisely that control - and searching the web for related keywords is likely to bring readers here for whom use of that control _is_ an option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use built-in WebBrowser control.

References at CodeProject:

For Managed HTML Rendering, see [Professional HTML Renderer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use)

For Dynamic HTML Rendering, see [Show Dynamic HTML in WinForm Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101403/Show-Dynamic-HTML-in-WinForm-Applications)

Comment: I have already tried the HtmlRenderer but it seems does not show the page css correctly.+1 anyway for the good suggestion
The second link uses a webbrowser control which I would not like to use as explained in the question

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way aside to render HTML to WinForms application and Professional HTMl Renderer is a good source of information for your case but use should refer to this link also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12172/An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML

Comment: I have found yet another link http://www.webprogrammingblog.com/c-sharp-firefox-web-browser-geckofx/ from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514328/how-to-show-html-formatted-content-without-image-in-a-winform

Comment: There is also [this](http://www.modeltext.com/html/index.aspx) HTML editor control, though it requires xhtml.

I want to improve the HTML Renderer, can you provide the HTML\CSS that didn't work for you, Thx.

Answer (score 38):

You can user web browser control.It can inject all html code directly.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html>hello <script>alert('hi');</script></html>";
```

Comment: as you can guess form my question I have already tried it. Please have a read at the question

Comment: works great! thanks.. didn't think there such an object like that in winforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
webBrowser1.Document.Write(yourHtmlText);
```