# Can I use web views while creating a windows application using c#.net in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to bring in Google calendar function into my windows app. I'm not getting it properly. When I tried, I got only the dates but I need  few other details also from the Google calendar. 
In Android I've seen web view, where I can use the URL. Is there something similar in this, so that it will help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to display the Google Calendar or are you just trying to get the data to display in you custom Calendar?

Comment: Display the calendar completely with most of it's features

Comment: Is it a WPF application? Winform or ????

Comment: it is winform app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724223/display-html-on-a-winform see the answer to this question