# How to embed an html file in C# Windows forms application in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, html

I have an HTML file, and I want to know how to know how to embed the file in a C# windows form application in Visual Studio 2019 (community edition). All I need is the html file  to show up in the same window the Windows Forms app is located in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display HTML on a winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724223/display-html-on-a-winform)

Comment: Was my answer of use to you?  Do you have any questions?  My suggestion comes from working code (_very_ lightly edited)

Answer (score 0):

This code is from more than a decade ago, but it works.

**First:**

- Create your HTML file
- Add it to your project
- Set the properties for the file to

  - Build Action: EmbeddedResource
  - Copy to Output Directory: Do Not Copy

That will put your HTML file contents in your assembly as an embedded resource.

Then use code like this (in my case the html file is `HelpText.htm`):

```
Assembly thisAssembly=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string appName=thisAssembly.GetName().Name;
helpTextStream=thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(appName+".HelpText.htm");
webBrowser1.DocumentStream=helpTextStream;
```

The `webBrowser1` property is a WebBrowser control on a Windows Forms form.

You should also include code to `Dispose` the `helpTextStream` when you close the form.